# Add class on body in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add class on body for certain page and that class to be visible for all languages for that page, because my side running on 7 languages?

For example if I have page About us on her body I want to add class and to be visible for other languages for page About us?

I

Comment: wordpress have a function `is_page(pagename)' then you can do an if statement on the body tag then add a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code:

```
if ( is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) ) {
   add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
       return array_merge( $classes, array( 'class-name' ) );
   } );
}
```

[Reference of filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/).